# deeplinking not showing correct storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, appdelegate

I have an app where I want to perform some deeplinking in.
When the app is open in the background the app opens on the correct page like expected. 
But when the app is closed and then opened from the link it goes to the launchStoryboard then to the main interface storyboard and then to the storyboard I want.
But in the main interface storyboard I'm calling the api and when this is finished my app goes back to the main interface storyboard but it should stay on the storyboard like it is when the app opens from the background
Any ideas on how to takle this issue?

I followed those urls to make this happen

https://www.raywenderlich.com/6080-universal-links-make-the-connection 
https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Answer (score 0):

I would check for different way you handle the url when handling it on

```
optional public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
```

vs

```
optional public func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool

optional public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
```

---

**About:**

```
optional public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

From the documentation:

> Summary
>
> Asks the delegate to open a resource specified by a URL, and provides
>   a dictionary of launch options. Declaration
>
> optional func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
>   options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
>   Discussion
>
> This method is not called if your implementations return false from
>   both the application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) and
>   application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) methods. (If only one of
>   the two methods is implemented, its return value determines whether
>   this method is called.) If your app implements the
>   applicationDidFinishLaunching(*:) method instead of
>   application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:), this method is called
>   to open the specified URL after the app has been initialized. If a URL
>   arrives while your app is suspended or running in the background, the
>   system moves your app to the foreground prior to calling this method.
>   There is no equivalent notification for this delegation method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the fix in my case was not having a storyboard in the main interface and do the check and set the storyboard manually according to if it is triggered from url or not